# how to make random placement of items only in positions of multiples of 20

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a game that is similar to mine sweeper. I am using windows forms and have created a mine class where there is a set number of mines placed on form load.

I have a user player who obviously moves around, both the player and mines are the same size, 20,20, currently the mines are set to randomly place on a panel, x(0,400) and y(0,360).

The player starts at a fixed point each time, 200,380 and has a movement of 20, what id like is to be able to ensure that the mines are placed at multiples of 20, so 20,20 40,40 etc so that when the player is moving around i do not get a position where the player ends up half way into the mine(if that makes sense).

I want it so that the player will either completely miss the mine or fully hit it.

```
class Mines
{

    // variables for movign the enemy ships
    public PictureBox m;
    public int xPos, yPos;
    public Boolean isDisposed = false;

    Random random = new Random();

    public Mines(Panel f)
    {
        m = new PictureBox();

        m.Width = 20;
        m.Height = 20;
        m.Image = Minefield.Properties.Resources.mine;
        m.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        m.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        m.Visible = true;


        xPos = random.Next(0, 400);
        yPos = random.Next(0,360);
        m.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);  // x and y position of the enemy for starting
        f.Controls.Add(m); // needed to add the control to the panel
    }

    public void placeMines(Panel f)
    {
        m.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
    }
}
```

That's the code i have for the mine class, i can provide more if needed, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to calculate the possible discreete steps given a stepwidth of `20`. And randomly choose the amount of steps you want to make. Here is a little example to show the workings:

```
Random random = new Random();   

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int stepWidth = 20; // 
    int maxStep = 400 / stepWidth; // here calculate the maximum number of step that can be made
    int stepAmount = random.Next(1, maxStep);       
    Console.WriteLine(stepAmount * stepWidth);
}
```

Output:

> 160
> 140
> 180
> 380
> 120
> 200
> 80
> 100
> 80
> 200

Comment: thanks, i gave it a go and it seems to be working great now

Comment: one last thing, what would i need to add to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @AdrianRowlands you would need to remember them. Save it in a List and check with contains if the list contains the new random number already. If so keep generating.

Comment: To avoid duplicates, you could also first create a list of possible values. Then select a random index from that list, use its value and remove from that list. Possibly recreate the list when it becomes empty